# gettext working locally, but not on the host server

Tags: php, gettext, php-gettext

I'm facing an odd issue with `gettext` in my **PHP** application. It works on my development machines *(Ubuntu 10.10 32 bit, 2 x Windows 7 64 bit, Windows 7 32 bit, all running XAMPP)*.

The production server is a paid host running some flavour of **Linux 64 bit**. I don't know exactly which. I can try to find out if it matters.

**Here is how I initialise gettext:**

```
//just FYI:
//$this->data['language'] == 'pl'
//dirname(__FILE__).'/../language/locale' ==
//'/home/mingos/public_html/example.com/application/controllers/../language/locale'

putenv('LANGUAGE='.$this->data['language']);
putenv('LANG='.$this->data['language']);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$this->data['language']);
setlocale(LC_ALL,$this->data['language']);

bindtextdomain($this->data['language'], dirname(__FILE__).'/../language/locale');
bind_textdomain_codeset($this->data['language'],'UTF-8');
textdomain($this->data['language']);
```

I ran `phpinfo()` on the server and found out that `gettext` is enabled and `safe_mode` is off, excluding the possibility `LC_ALL` being unmodifiable (I think).

**The compiled gettext catalog is:**

```
/home/mingos/public_html/example.com/application/language/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/pl.mo
```

So the path set in `bindtextdomain` is correct.

I do not get any notices or warnings, but `gettext` does not extract translations from my the catalog, returning simply the strings it is fed, e.g. `gettext('About us')` returns `About us` instead of `O nas`.

The catalog itself is compiled correctly using `poEdit` and is confirmed to be working on my 4 dev machines.

What might be the other possible causes of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gettext will only support the installed locales. If you have a shell on your hosting provider you should run 'locale -a' to see a list of installed locales. You may need to contact your hosting provider to have them install the necessary language pack for pl.

Comment: Hm, indeed, it has 'pl_PL' installed, not 'pl'... odd, since it's a Polish host... Anyway, I found out it also has 'en_GB', 'no_NO' and 'es_ES', which completes my list of sought after locales. It does seem to work now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but I wanted to explain why it worked on Windows and not on Linux. Windows servers don't use the same locale names as Linux servers. For example, in Windows you will have "en", but on Linux you'll have "en_EN". It's the same with Polish, on Windows it will be "pl" and on Linux it will be "pl_PL". You'll need to have some type of test for your local or live server and change the locale string accordingly.